# Primefaces fileDownload redirect to another page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem whith the component fileDownload of Primefaces. When I am triyng to download my file the application redirects to another page that does not exist. It happens in my server and not capable to reproduce this behavior in my local environment.

This is the button

```html
<p:commandButton value="Descargar Detalle" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" styleClass="buttons-form">
   <p:fileDownload value="#{detalleBaking.fileReporte}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This is the creation of the file

```java
File archivo = new File(nombreReporte);
fileReporte = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(archivo), "application/pdf", nombreReporte.replace(rutaDocumento, ""));
```

The file is been creating in a PostConstruct annotated method, and the file exist in the path provided.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you know `p:fileDownload` is causing this problem? Might be a reverse proxy or whatever.

Comment: The problem was the name of the file. I changed from "Confirmación Hacienda" to "ConfirmacionHacienda" and now i am able to download the file